# In C#, how can I keep all my items in a listbox from changing to the color I set last?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, listbox

I have researched how to change colors for each line and here is my code using public variable itemColor which is a Brush

```
...

public Brush itemColor;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    itemColor = Brushes.Purple;
    listBox1.Items.Add("Purple");
    itemColor = Brushes.Green;
    listBox1.Items.Add("Green");
    itemColor = Brushes.Red;
    listBox1.Items.Add("Red");
}

private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();
    e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), listBox1.Font, 
                          itemColor, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}

...
```

I have set the listbox DrawMode to OwnerDrawFixed and all items turn to red.  Can anyone see my probably silly error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listBox1_DrawItem` gets called every time the control needs to be redrawn, such as on item add/remove or selection change. You can see this by adding a second button to your form and doing this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    itemColor = Brushes.Blue;
}
```

After you click the second button, the next time the `ListBox` is redrawn, all the items' text will be blue.

---

There is most likely a better way to do this, but one way you could handle this is to make a class to represent you items with a `Text` and `Brush` field and add fill your ListBox with those. Then on the DrawItem handler, you cast the `Items[e.Index]` to your class and reference the text and color fields. Something like this:

```
class Entry
{
    public string Text;
    public Brush Color;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(new Entry { Text = "Purple", Color = Brushes.Purple });
    listBox1.Items.Add(new Entry { Text = "Green",  Color = Brushes.Green  });
    listBox1.Items.Add(new Entry { Text = "Red",    Color = Brushes.Red    });
}

private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    var currentItem = listBox1.Items[e.Index] as Entry;

    e.DrawBackground();
    e.Graphics.DrawString(currentItem.Text, listBox1.Font, currentItem.Color,
                          e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

Comment: I just tried another button to later add a green line, and it turns all four of  the lines green after the first three were red.

Comment: @TimWayne ha, ha, I was just updating my answer with something very similar for you to play around with when the `DrawItem` event handler gets fired. I also included a simple (crude) solution that I tested out and works for this example.

Comment: I like it better code wise anyway, plus it works!  Thanks